# JAXB mapping xml with different sub tags to the same java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi all I'm learning some XML and I have an issue mapping the following XML to a java object.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test:wallet 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:test="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:testTwo="http://google.com">

    <xsi:container name="container1">
        <test:val>hello-world</test:val>
    </xsi:container>
    <xsi:container name="container2">
        <test:val>
            <testTwo:subContainer name="subContainer1" value="hello-world-sub-container">
            </testTwo:subContainer>
        </test:val>
    </xsi:container>

</test:wallet>
```

So far i've come up with the following java code.

Wallet.java

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.acme.xml.Container;

@XmlRootElement(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {
    @XmlElement(name = "container")
    ArrayList<Container> containers;
}
```

Container.java

```java
public class Container {
    @XmlElement(name="val")
    private ContainerValue val;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

}
```

ContainerValue.java

```java
public class ContainerValue {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public Object val;

    // EDIT can this class give me both the correct type for String and SubContainer once the java object is created from the xml?
}
```

But I don't understand how ContainerValue can host sometimes a string value and sometimes a SubContainer value

Comment: Using `Object val` instead of `String` could handle both..

Comment: @xerx593 hmm intressting. However, this would mean that once The java object is created the type would be something else right? Is it possible to have the type remain? so that if its a string you get String if it is a subContainer you get the SubContainer java object

Comment: ..but XmlValue could be a problem/need substitute(?)

Comment: ```java
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public Object val;
```

I tried this and it works for the SubContainer but not the string.

Comment: It seems the object is turned into ´ElementNSImpl´ instead of String and SubContainer